# "The specified program requires a newer version of windows" Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, windows, updates, ide

I need to install Atmel studio 7.0 in my PC which is windows 7 Ultimate (Version 6.1 Build version 7600).

If i tried to install it is showing error message **"The specified program requires a newer version of windows".**

Is there a way to solve this issue  without updating windows?
Can i update windows 7.0 to build version 7601.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Hi Crackhead.h, welcome to SuperUser. I feel your question would probably be better directed at the developers of Atmel Studio, from a perspective of "How do can you install their product on my current PC"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Atmel Studio Requirements](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/GUID-ECD8A826-B1DA-44FC-BE0B-5A53418A47BD/index.html?GUID-8F63ECC8-08B9-4CCD-85EF-88D30AC06499) states:

> #### Supported Operating Systems
>
> Windows 7 Service Pack 1 or higher

Build 7600 is Windows 7 **without** SP1, so download and install SP1 and it should work.

Microsoft recommends using Windows Update to install service packs.

[Windows Service Pack and Update Center](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/14162/windows-service-pack-and-update-center)

Comment: You are very welcome @crackhead.h